# What is the difference between '\0' and "\0" in C++ string

Tags: c++, string, null-terminated

I tried to add a null terminator (`\0`) in a string in two ways.
One using `'\0'` and another using `"\0"`, and I'm getting different outputs in both cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string test1 = "";
    test1 += "\0";
    cout << test1.size() << endl;
    
    string test2 = "";
    test2 += '\0';
    cout << test2.size() << endl;
}
```

I am getting output

```
0
1
```

Can anyone please explain why the string is taking `'\0'` as a character not a null terminator? If I print `test1` or `test2`, it will print an empty string.

Comment: One(`'\0`') is a *"character literal"* and the other(`"\0"`) is a *"string literal"*.

Comment: C++ string is not null-terminated, you can glue a NUL char (`'\0'`) to it if you want. C-style string is null-terminated, so `"\0"` is taken to mean a zero-length empty string.

Comment: You don't need any of this.

Comment: *I tried to add a null terminator (\0) in string in two ways.* -- Why?  A `std::string` knows its own length without any null-terminator (the `length` or `size` member functions of `std::string`).  It seems you are getting confused with C-style strings, where the null-terminator is required.

Comment: @teapot418 — `”\0”` is a string literal with **two** characters, both `'\0'`. An empty string is simply `””`; it holds one character, a `'\0'`.

Answer (score 11):

`'\0'` is a single character. A `char` with value `0`.

`"\0"` is an array of two characters. A `const char[2]` with value `{ 0, 0 }` (The first is the one specified in the code for the string literal, and the second is the nul terminator added by the compiler to all string literals).

When you have `test2 += '\0';`, this passes the one character to the `string` object to append to it. The function called is `std::string::operator+=(char)`.

When you have `test2 += "\0";`, this passes a pointer to the array's 1st element to the `string` object, calling `std::string::operator+=(const char*)`. This is interpreted as a C-string, which can't have embedded nul characters. There is no way to tell between `""` and `"\0"` when you only have a pointer, since the first character is `'\0'` in both cases and that looks like the end of the string.

If you want to use embedded nul characters, you have to pass the size separately. This can be done with [`std::string::append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), eg:

```cpp
// ptr+size
test2.append("\0", 1);

// iterator pair
const auto& str = "\0";
test2.append(std::begin(str), std::end(str)-1);  // (-1 for the extra nul terminator)
```

Or, using a `string_view`, which carries its size with it:

```cpp
using namespace std::literals::string_view_literals;
test2 += "\0"sv;
// "\0"sv.size() == 1
```

Comment: If I add "\0" to a string, it is treated as a null terminator, causing the string to be considered empty. However, if I add '\0', it seems, it is not treating it as null character. Even when I use test2.empty(), it returns false, indicating non-emptiness. However, when I print test2, empty string is printing, creating the impression that the string is empty despite having content.

Comment: @RahulKumawat `std::string` isn't null terminated so adding a null character to it simply adds a character. Whatever method you're using for printing the string likely just doesn't print anything for null characters

Comment: @RahulKumawat When you print the string, how do you expect the character `\0` to be displayed. Although I've used terminals where a control characters had a repressentation ("nul" written diagonally in very small letters), most terminal devices will simply ignore it.